# fail to open file in laravel.The localhost page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, laravel, apache, ubuntu

When I try to run my project, I am getting this error in terminal.

[image]

> [Fri Mar 30 14:36:23 2018] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>   [Fri Mar 30 14:36:23 2018] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/imporeexcel/public/server.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: The error message is crystal clear, isn't it? We cannot tell you if such file exists, where, why it cannot be loaded...

Comment: @arkascha what should i do to resolve this problem..please help me

Comment: You should find the file mentioned not to be found, obviously. And then conclude what settings need to be changed so that it _will_ be found.

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed the issue, it seems a bug in laravel 5.6.12 installer. It deletes the server.php upon the first artisan serve.

A temporary solution will be to create another project then copy that newly created server.php this will solve it.

EDIT:
If your anti-virus is avast, you need to add exception there, I have a response in GitHub that avast considers it as a threat.